# Running neo4j on windows without administrative rights

Tags: windows, neo4j

Is it possible to run Neo4j (the Zip archive version) on windows 10 without having administrative rights?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in console mode.

```
> cd neo4j-enterprise-3.2.1
> bin\neo4j.bat console
```

Hope this helps,
Tom